# Try y Except en ruby

Tags: python, ruby

estoy aprendiendo a programar en ruby, mi lenguaje principal es python, por lo que me entró la duda si hay algún equivalente al try y except de python en ruby:

```
try:
    print("No hubo errores")
except:
    print("Si hubo errores")
```

¿hay algo similar o igual en ruby?

Muchas gracias a los que se tomen el tiempo para responder esto :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, puedes utilizar `begin`/`rescue`/`ensure`/`end`<sup>1</sup>; por ejemplo:

```
begin
  # código que puede generar error
  puts "No hubo errores"
rescue
  # este código se ejecuta únicamente si el código en `begin` arroja una excepción
  puts "Sí hubo errores"
ensure
  # este código se ejecuta siempre, sin importar si se arroja una excepción.
end
```

Cuando utilizas `rescue` se recomienda *cachar* la excepción específica que tu código puede generar o, en el peor de los casos, *cachar* `StandardError`:

```
begin
  # ...
rescue StandardError => e
  puts Error: "e.description"
end
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Tanto `rescue` como `ensure` son opcionales.*</sup>

Comment: Buena respuesta. Añadir que se pueden colocar diferentes rescue en el código dentro del begin, cada uno para diferente tipo de excpeciones. También se puede colocar un else que se ejecutaría en el caso de que no haya excepciones

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente ya no es necesario utilizar begin.
Si defines una función, puedes realizarlo así:

```
def my_function
  # some logic 
rescue 
  # rescue logic
end
```

Y otras formas mas compactas